# Expected p-values from a series of trials

Tags: p-value, multiple-comparisons, clinical-trials

I'm looking at this toxicology study (http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0041008X1500085X). The study has a negative control group, a positive control group and three treatment groups which receive one of three doses of the chemical of interest.  Setting the positive control group aside, because it tests the relationship of a different substance, there are four independent groups.  After the treatment, the rats are bred to three generations F1, F2, and F3.  There are then seven outcomes of interest.  Each treatment group and each treatment's group offspring are measured on each of the seven DV.

First, am I right in saying that these are roughly equivalent to 4 (treatments) * 3 (generations) * 7 (dependent variables) = 84 independent experiments or trials?

Would I further be correct in saying that, assuming no relationship, one would expect 84 *0.05 = ~4 results that would be statistically significant at the 0.05 level?